Media Foundation Video Capture Engine fails to capture the video on disconnecting the device
I am developing a windows desktop application to record video in .mp4 format from a USB camera using the Media Foundation Capture Engine sample code. In this application, everything works fine until I disconnect my camera while the video is recording. The issue is that when I disconnect the camera during recording, the video file gets corrupted.Here i have noticed that the size of the video file is increased but while opening that file i am getting this error

When I debugged the issue, I found that when destroying the Capture Engine, CaptureSink->RemoveAllStreams() fails. I have noticed this issue only at a resolution of 640x480.
Is there any reason for this, or can anyone recommend a possible way of capturing without the file getting corrupted, even if the device is disconnected during the capture?

This is more like a "behavior by design". MPEG-4 media sink is not expected to produce a playable file unless properly finalized. The recording is not finalized because of an error during the recording session. Some attempt to work this around by using another sink, fragmented MP4 sink in particular. Perhaps the proper solution would be to use a custom media sink, and take recording out of the capture engine so that you could finalize your partial recording yourselves.

But i am facing this issue only for 640*480 resolution.Is there any reason for that??

There are no details in the description to explain the difference. I would assume that with other resolutions the engine supplies additional scaler and it absorbs the error letting you or the engine finalize the recording. As it is happening behind the scene. it is hard to catch what exactly is happening.
